# ¿Los usuarios nuevo con poca reputación, no pueden comentar en su pregunta?

Tags: soporte, comentarios, usuarios-nuevos

Despues de leer esta "pregunta":

[¿Por qué cualquiera puede responder y no cualquiera puede preguntar?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1921/por-qu%C3%A9-cualquiera-puede-responder-y-no-cualquiera-puede-preguntar)

De todo lo que el usuario mencionó, esta parte me llamó la atención pero no por el contexto en el que lo redactaba:

> ...ya que la cierran por duplicada, **el usuario no puede comentar ya que**
>   **es nuevo** y no tiene la suficiente reputación como para poner un
>   comentario

**duplicada** o podría ser por x motivo, pero tiene sentido la parte que comenta de que el usuario es nuevo y no puede comentar para aclarar o cualquier cosa sobre su pregunta. "Sí puede editarla" pero eso no es el punto, el punto es_ ¿Qué tan cierto es esto? No recuerdo si un usuario nuevo puede comentar en su propia pregunta aun no teniendo reputacion. Si esto es cierto, quizás se deba de mirar el que los nuevos usuarios puedan comentar en su pregunta, ya sea porque la van a cerrar o por cualquier otra cosa.

Comment: Ya vi. Los nuevos usuarios pueden comentar __*en sus propias publicaciones*__. O sea, si pueden comentar en sus preguntas. Dejo un ejemplo que muestra evidencia objetiva de mi comentario: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68307/

Comment: @toledano Gracias por aclararme esta duda, y por el tiempo empleado en buscar una referencia. Saludos

Comment: Parece que el usuario al entrar nuevamente al sitio no entra con la primera cuenta creada, sino con una segunda cuenta. Quizás es un bug en SOes.

Comment: Me refiero a si pueden comentar en otra pregunta, papus.

Comment: @TatoBroh la verdad es que no se cuando pueden empezar a comentar, papus.

Comment: Con 50 de reputación papu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Sí pueden.

De la página de privilegios [Comentar En Todas Partes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment):

> Nota que *siempre* puedes comentar en tus propias publicaciones, y en cualquier parte de tus preguntas. Sin embargo, comentar en las publicaciones de otros usuarios es un privilegio.

Traducido: cualquier usuario, independientemente de su reputación, puede comentar en:

- Sus publicaciones.
- Las respuestas a sus preguntas.

---

Tal y como comenta Luiggi, puede ser que el texto que mencionas se refiera a alguna casuística común: un usuario no registrado que publicó una pregunta, después volvió a entrar y a efectos de Stack Overflow es otro usuario. Pero vaya, si el usuario está registrado eso no ocurrirá.